# How to match CRLF in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, newline

Suppose I have a text file in which the first line is a return and second line is a word "second"

I run cmdlet:

```
PS > $([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Tmp\Foo.txt"))[2] -eq 's'
```

Result is True, the third chars is 's', So the first two char is stand for a new line

But when I run

```
PS > $([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Tmp\Foo.txt"))[1] -eq '`n'
```

or

```
PS > $([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Tmp\Foo.txt"))[1] -eq '`r'
```

All of them return False

How to match a newline in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

```
$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\t.txt"))[1] -eq "`n"
```

Note the double quotes instead of the single ones.